# No puedo llamar a un funcion de javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

Bueno , mi problema que quiero obtener los dtos de la 'funcion success : `function(json)`' ,el problema es que no la lee ... ¿Que esta mal?

```
$('#chat-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : '/post/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { msgbox : $('#chat-msg').val() },
        dataType: 'json',

        success : function(json){
            $('#chat-msg').val('');
            $('#msg-list').append('<li class="text-right list-group-item">' + json.msg + '</li>');
            var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
            chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
        }
    });     });
```

Comment: Mire que error te sale en la consola.

Comment: no estas definiendo bien la url: `url : '/post/'`

Comment: revisa la url `url : '/post/',`

Comment: Hola @AlbertArias  me salen estas dos excepciones  ... tiene algo que ver  con la carga de la funcion   El uso de document.createAttribute() está desaprobado. Use en su lugar element.setAttribute().  ,
El uso de setAttributeNode() está desaprobado. Use en su lugar setAttribute().

Comment: ¿La variable `json` tiene datos?.

Comment: si ya lo solucione ,,, me faltaba una coma al termino de la funcion ... gracias a todos por los comentarios

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, la url no va a ninguna pagina del servidor. Solo estas marcando a que carpeta, pero no lo direccionas a un archivo en especifico. Saludos!